# yammer oauth against external network?

Tags: oauth-2.0, yammer

With yammer OAuth, is it possible to register an app on an external yammer network and then authenticate users against this external network, rather than the primary network?

*update 9/30/2014 --* to clarify, my goal is to use yammer oauth as a gateway to my own (python based) application, allowing only users of the external network in.

i've got this working on a non-SSO primary & external network combo.  after the external network user successfully signs in via yammer, and they are redirected to my callback url, i make a call to /networks/current. i can then check to see if the target external network id appears in their list, and if so let them in.

when i switch my application to use API credentials for an app registered on an SSO enabled primary network & non-SSO external network, and try to login with an external network user, things stop working.  after the yammer sign in process completed (note: yammer kicks them out to the SSO endpoint and sign in is completed there), and the user is redirected back to my app, i get a `403 forbidden error`. the process never makes it to my call to get their networks...if i try logging in with a user of the primary (SSO enabled network), it works (my custom login fails them since they are not a member of the correct network).

Answer (score 1):

You need to globalize your SSO App to get things work. For this you need to raise a request to the Yammer helpdesk.

Comment: Can you share link to helpdesk?

Comment: You can log your query at https://portal.office.com/Home
For this you would need Microsoft's credentials. 

Alternatively you can post your query on this forum,
https://community.office365.com/en-us/f

Answer (score 0):

I tried this same implementation recently and didn't work because the userID (of the authenticated user) that's associated with the external network's access token is the home network's UserID. I worked around it by:

1. Opening Chrome
2. Sign into the external network
3. Right click -> Inspect Element
4. Click Network Tab
5. Refresh page
6. Doubleclick on any row containing ‘…./api/v1/…’
7. Click headers tab in side panel
8. Token is found in “Authorization: Bearer …”

You can then pass that bearer token in your REST [request header](http://developer.yammer.com/authentication/#a-requests)

NOTE: Mine was an SSO enabled network so your mileage may differ :)

Comment: thank you for the response. i've successfully found a workaround to accomplish this, but currently i can't get it to work with an SSO enabled network (the production network for this app). given you have some yammer SSO experience, perhaps you can shed some light on [my issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127455/yammer-oauth2-returning-403-client-error-forbidden)?

Comment: sorry, reading you response again, i may have misread.  the method you described certainly works to get the token. how i then go about using that to authenticate my application users with yammer? please see the updated post for clarification regarding the goal of my app.

Comment: once you get the token, you can then set the authorization header with the token, like so:                                                                                               <script> 
yam.platform.setAuthToken("VALID_TOKEN_VALUE", function() {
yam.getLoginStatus(
function(response) {
if (response.authResponse) {
console.log("logged in");

}
else {
alert("not logged in")
}
}
);
});
</script>