# Unable to fetch token of user in external network yammer

Tags: yammer

I have created an app in Yammer client applications using that client id and client secret i can able to fetch access token only for the user in the same network. When i am trying to fetch for users in external network (other than the network in which i have registered my app) with the client id and client secret and external network user's authorisation code, it was throwing 403 error code - You are not allowed fetch access token.Is there any way to get access token for all users with the single application's client id and secret.

Will Yammer App directory resolve my problem?

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127455/yammer-oauth2-returning-403-client-error-forbidden/30522798#30522798